# Open Window that has been put in tab or other options?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm hoping that someone may be able to help me out.

My Home page (Home.html) has a link to a mp3player located at (mp3.html) 
On the mp3player page there is a link back to Home.html

If the user clicks on the link to the Mp3 player I would like for the music to continue to play even if the link to home.html is pressed.

What I would like to avoid is having multiple tabs from being opened if the user would re-click one of these links.

Also I would like to have the appropriate page to open when it's link is pressed instead of being locked in a tab and not displaying.

- The mp3 player isn't affected by being refreshed.

I would prefer not to have different tabs open if at all possible.

This really got me stumped. I've tried different things out only to either be stuck choosing a tab or loosing the music from playing.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you both for replying:

The sixty one link basically is the output of what I've been looking for, so I intend to use the Ajax method.

Initially I was looking to keep things as simple as possible yet eliminating the use of tabs or having a floating mp3player. But after thinking I may incorporate other features as well Ajax seems the way I should go.

Thank you both again for your time and for resolving my problem.

Comment: You can pick favourite answer and mark as accepted, as a recommendation for all guys which will check this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can program your site with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), so index page won't be reloaded but supplemented by content loaded be demand - Google Mail is a good example. Not a task for beginner, though.
2. You can use HTML frames ([see examples](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_frames.asp)) and load index and player at the same time in one tab. Very easy and may fit your needs, but makes your site harder to link to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the AJAX version as well, it's a nicer user experience. If there's a player somewhere in another tab, that's pretty annoying for the user to find if he wants to turn it off or change a track. Check out [the Sixtyone](http://www.thesixtyone.com/) and how they're solving the problem.